# kdb/Q: How to select rows where at least one column is not null?

Tags: null, kdb

I have a table that looks like this:

| ID | Name | 1_Day_Time | 2_Day_Time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2B | May | 762 |  |
| 8D | Air |  | 142 |
| W2 | Tim | 908 | 332 |
| 9H | Bee |  |  |
| 5E | Ice | 712 |  |

How do I only select those rows with at least one non-null in the 1_Day_Time and 2_Day_Time columns in kdb/Q?

My intended output is below, with the row of ID 9H removed as there are nulls in both 1_Day_Time and 2_Day_Time columns:

| ID | Name | 1_Day_Time | 2_Day_Time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2B | May | 762 |  |
| 8D | Air |  | 142 |
| W2 | Tim | 908 | 332 |
| 5E | Ice | 712 |  |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i'd advise that you not use column names starting with a number (e.g. prefer "One_Day_Time" over "1_Day_Time"), otherwise you'll need functional select.  But here are a few possible solutions:

```
q)show t: ([] ID:`2B`8D`W2`9H`5E; Name:`May`Air`Tim`Bee`Ice; One_Day_Time: 762 0N 908 0N 712; Two_Day_Time: 0N 143 332 0N 0N)
ID Name One_Day_Time Two_Day_Time
---------------------------------
2B May  762
8D Air               143
W2 Tim  908          332
9H Bee
5E Ice  712

q)select from t where not null[One_Day_Time] & null[Two_Day_Time]
ID Name One_Day_Time Two_Day_Time
---------------------------------
2B May  762
8D Air               143
W2 Tim  908          332
5E Ice  712

q)select from t where (not null One_Day_Time) | (not null Two_Day_Time)
ID Name One_Day_Time Two_Day_Time
---------------------------------
2B May  762
8D Air               143
W2 Tim  908          332
5E Ice  712

q)select from t where {not all null x} each (One_Day_Time,'Two_Day_Time)
ID Name One_Day_Time Two_Day_Time
---------------------------------
2B May  762
8D Air               143
W2 Tim  908          332
5E Ice  712
```

Comment: Thanks so much! Just curious, why can't column names start with a number?

Comment: "The first character in a name cannot be numeric or the underscore" as per https://code.kx.com/q/basics/syntax/

Comment: Note you can however use xcol to rename a column so that it begins with a number, but if you wish to select from that table, you'd need to use functional select: ******************************************************** t: ([] Col1: 1 2 3; Col2: 3 4 5; Col3:6 7 8); t: xcol[`$("1_Day_Time"; "2_Day_Time"; "Col3"); t]; show ?[t; (); 0b; (`$("1_Day_Time"; "2_Day_Time"))!(`$("1_Day_Time"; "2_Day_Time"))]

Answer (score 2):

If you had many columns to check (instead of 2) you could use this example with a list of columns. The advantage is that is easy to add more columns for consideration quite easily:

```
q)tab:([]ID:`2B`8D`W2`9H`5E;Name:`May`Air`Tim`Bee`Ice;One_Day_Time:762 0N 908 0N 712;Two_Day_Time:0N 142 332 0N 0N)
q)cls:`One_Day_Time`Two_Day_Time
q)?[tab;enlist(not;(all;enlist,{(null;x)}'[cls]));0b;()]
ID Name One_Day_Time Two_Day_Time
---------------------------------
2B May  762
8D Air               142
W2 Tim  908          332
5E Ice  712
```

It's also useful if those column names may vary.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution that avoids qsql or functional selects. Seems at least as fast as the qsql or functional select answers:

```
q)t:([]ID:`2B`8D`W2`9H`5E;Name:`May`Air`Tim`Bee`Ice;One_Day_Time:762 0N 908 0N 712;Two_Day_Time:0N 142 332 0N 0N)
q)c:`One_Day_Time`Two_Day_Time
q)t where not all null t c
ID Name One_Day_Time Two_Day_Time
---------------------------------
2B May  762
8D Air               142
W2 Tim  908          332
5E Ice  712
```

Easy to scale to additional columns also.